# Recognize that user select Yes Or No in Joptionpane

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I have a frame that when user want to delete a record, a warning pane should be displayed.

But, Now i have to recognize that if user select Yes, Then i remove selected row and if select no, Don't remove it!

How?

```
if (e.getSource() == deleteUser) {
JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(rootPane, "Are You Sure To Delete?", "Delete User", WIDTH);

// if yes, Then remove
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the JavaDocs...

```
public static int showConfirmDialog(Component parentComponent,
                    Object message,
                    String title,
                    int optionType)
                             throws HeadlessException

Brings up a dialog where the number of choices is determined by the optionType parameter.

Parameters:
    parentComponent - determines the Frame in which the dialog is displayed; if null, or if the parentComponent has no Frame, a default Frame is used
    message - the Object to display
    title - the title string for the dialog
    optionType - an int designating the options available on the dialog: YES_NO_OPTION, YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION, or OK_CANCEL_OPTION
Returns:
    an int indicating the option selected by the user
```

The return type will be dependent on the value you pass to the `optionType` parameter

This would suggest you should do something like...

```
int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(rootPane, "Are You Sure To Delete?", "Delete User", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
if (result == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
    // Do something here
}
```

Have a look at [How to make dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more details...

Comment: Remember, the JavaDocs and tutorials are your friend.  If you have already read through them and are still stuck, you need to highlight this in you questions, we will be more kind in our answers for your efforts ;)